# Mongoose-pagination visual with mustache

Tags: node.js, mongodb, twitter-bootstrap, express, mongoose

I'm currently working on getting the `mongoose-pagination` package working and I believe I have it implemented correctly.

I have the following:

route

```
router.get('/dashboard', ensureAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
  User.paginate({}, { page: 1, limit: 6 }, function(err, result) {
    result.limit - 6
    result.page - 1
  });

  User.find({}, function(err, users) {
    res.render('dashboard/index.hbs', {
      pageTitle: 'Dashboard',
      users: users
    });
  });
});
```

and I have implemented the package in the `user.js` and called `UserSchema.plugin(mongoosePaginate);`.

However I am unsure on how to get a visible implementation of this working so it is clickable through the pages.

I am using Bootstrap 3 and the mustache templating engine.

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstand how the plugin works.

Try this:

```
router.get('/dashboard', ensureAuthenticated, (req, res) => {

    // get the page and limit from querystring 
    // assumming you use url like this /dashboard?limit=6&page=1

    var limit = parseInt(req.query.limit) || 6;
    var page = parseInt(req.query.page) || 1;

    User.paginate({}, { page: page, limit: limit }, function(err, result) {
        // result has bellow properties

        // result.docs
        // result.total
        // result.limit
        // result.page
        // result.pages

        res.render('dashboard/index.hbs', {
            pageTitle: 'Dashboard',
            users: result.docs,
            total: result.total,
            limit: result.limit,
            page: result.page,
            pages: result.pages
        });
    });
});
```

To render users use something like this:

```
<table>
{{#each users}}
    <tr><td>{{school}}</td><td>{{city}}</td><td>{{email}}</td><td>actions here</td></tr>
{{/each}}
</table>
```

To render links use:

```
Number of records: {{total}}
Number of pages: {{pages}}
Current page: {{page}}
<a href="/dashboard?limit={{limit}}&page=1">Page 1</a>
<a href="/dashboard?limit={{limit}}&page=2">Page 2</a>
<a href="/dashboard?limit={{limit}}&page=3">Page 3</a>
<a href="/dashboard?limit={{limit}}&page=4">Page 4</a>
```

Comment: There's no way to get this dynamically? x amount of records equals x amount  of pages?

Comment: Also I still do want users to show no information is being displayed now https://gyazo.com/113e49525b0533220768757587fa5279

Comment: So this works, however one slight issue I'm having to do this https://gyazo.com/74e649b0db5fd47f32aa260503977e43 it would be nice if this was dynamic because the more users that sign up the more I'm going to have to change the manually every time per 6 users. Also it would be nice if the bootstrap activate class worked on the clicked page.

Comment: Of course this can be dynamic. You can either implement it yourself or use existing handlebars helpers https://www.google.cz/search?q=handlebars.js+pagination